# Error al hacer una resta en DAO JAVA jpa

Tags: java, jpa

Tengo un DAO (Data Access Object) para crear un historial. Lo que busco hacer es al momento de crear un historial haga una resta y ese valor se lo ponga a una variable.

Sin embargo, me arroja nullpointerexception. ¿Hay algún problema en mi código?

```
   public boolean crearHistorial2(Equipo equipo, Usuario usuario, Integer kilo, String ubi, Integer kilore) {
    Historial historial = new Historial();
    historial.setEquipo(equipo);
    historial.setUbicacion(ubi);
    historial.setUsuario(usuario);
    historial.setKilometrost(kilo);
    int valor1;
    valor1= Integer.parseInt(equipo.getKilometrost());
    historial.setKilometros(kilo - valor1);
    historial.setFecha(new Date());
    return jpam.persistirEntidad(historial);
}
```

El error me lo arroja en la resta y quiero que el valor de esa resta lo tengo el atributo kilómetros.

Comment: Si tienes una NPE (NullPointerException) si existe un problema en tu código. Para encontrarlo es entre útil y necesario de compartir la excepción por lo menos hasta que lista tu propio código, y facilita mucho el trabajo si puedes marcar la línea en tu código que te marca la excepción.

Answer (score 0):

si el error te da aquí historial.setKilometros(kilo - valor1);
Y te da un nullPointer, entiendo que alguno de los dos valores es nulo, usa el debugger y mira que valor tienen los dos campos antes de ejecutar la resta.

Ahora bien, yo veo un comportamiento extraño en tu código, si kilo es un Integer y valor1 un int, ¿Por qué los restas?, quizás es más fácil si creas valor1 como Integer directamente y te evitas el casteo extraño que tuviste que hacer para asignarle valor a valor1.

Yo miraría el valor de los dos campos para comprobar que ninguno sea nulo y trataría de hacer valor1 Integer para hacer la resta Integer - Integer y no int - Integer.

Saludos.

Comment: Recomiendo que agregues un ejemplo de codigo